# mysql inner join speed efficiency

Tags: mysql

I'm working with logic on creating queries with inner join.

In theory, would it speed up the process is you started with a smaller table?

Say I'm comparing keys across two tables.  Table A only has 4 rows.  Table B has 100.

So would:

```
SELECT * FROM `a` INNER JOIN `b` ON `a`.`key` = `b`.`key` WHERE `b`.`key`='value'
```

run faster than:

```
SELECT * FROM `b` INNER JOIN `a` ON `b`.`key` = `a`.`key` WHERE `b`.`key`='value'
```

**EDIT:** I've tried this with much larger data sets (10,000+ entries) and have always seen varied results.  I tried researching and couldn't find a definitive answer.  If this question is too vague, apologies.

Comment: Test it yourself, let us know.

Comment: Have you tried to run this yourself? Just generate some big data sets and run your queries!

Answer (score 1):

no, The combination would be the same.

4X100 = 100X4 (one match doesnt mean its unique - so all will have to be looked at)

Even if the a.key and b.key columns were indexed the index would be used the rows needed would still be reduced and multiplied in a similar way to above.

Smaller sets would (i assume) have more difference as caching can occur at the CPU, But the query optimiser should spot that and rewrite to the best execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` is cartesian product of two tables + conditions.

Another syntax of this query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `a`, `b` WHERE `a`.`key` = `b`.`key` AND `b`.`key`='value'
```

Order of tables in `FROM` clause doesn't matter. So I believe, that both queries do actually the same, but you should check it on larger sample of data than 100 rows to verify that.